# Ошибка CORS при работе с API

Tags: javascript, ajax, асинхронность, cors

[У Pinboard есть API](https://pinboard.in/api/). Когда я хочу обратится к нему из браузера мне выдает ошибку CORS.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '****' from origin 'http://localhost:1234'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

Каким образом её можно исправить?

P.S. Обращаюсь я через такую функцию:

```
function makeRequest(method){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.pinboard.in/v1/' + method + '?auth_token=' + token, true);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if (this.status == '200'){
                resolve(this.response);
            } else {
                console.log('err');
            }
        }
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            reject(new Error("Network Error"));
        };

        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: Откуда вы отправляйте ? какой сервер ? или webpack ?

Comment: @nihao использую дев сервер сборщика parcel

Answer (score 0):

У упаковщика PARCEL можно указать proxy, как и в webpack. То есть делавть pull request.

что-то на подобии этого:

```
// package.json
 "proxy" : {
    "path": "service",
    "host": "http://scooterlabs.com/echo"
 },
```

> Он берет запрос и перенаправляет его на host, но в нетворках вы все
>   равно увидите запрос идущий на localhost. Это так и должно быть

По ссылке узнаете больше - [ТАП](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/2477)

Или вот еще интересная штука(реализовано на уровне компонентов) - [ТАП](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-proxy-server)